# help in Laplace and partial fractions

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

Can any one teach me how to solve C2.(a) and (b) step by step?

---

**C2. (a)** Resolve $\frac{1}{s^2(s^2+s+1)}$ into partial fractions of the form $\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{s^2}+\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+s+1}$. 
Hence, resolve $\frac{1}{s(s^2+s+1)}$ into its partial fractions.

**C2. (b)** Find
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{s}{s^2+s+1}\right\}.$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math SX! Can you show a bit of your effort on this so far? This way it is easier to help you! What have you tried?

Comment: 1 = A + B +  Cs + D
s2 (s2  + s +1) s s2 s2 + s +1
1 = As (s2  + s +1) + B (s2  + s +1) + (Cs + D ) s2
1 = As3 + As2 + As + Bs2 + Bs + B + Cs3 + Ds2  
1 = ( A + C ) s3 + ( A + B + D ) s2 + ( A + B ) s + B

this is what is did until after this i am not sure how to do..!

Comment: Hi @user119006...and welcome to Math SX! Can you post a comment (or why not an answer) using the proper markup? With such a poor formatting, even a very good content is not properly readable.

Comment: Is this seeking some online help for your test? XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(a)** The function
$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(z^2+z+1)}$$
has a double pole in $z=0$ and a simple pole in $z=e^{\pm 2\pi i/3}$, since $z^2+z+1=\frac{z^3-1}{z-1}$. This gives:
$$ f(z)=\frac{A}{z^2}+\frac{B}{z}+\frac{C}{z-\omega}+\frac{D}{z-\omega^2}+g(z)$$
where $g(z)$ is a holomorphic function. By computing:
$$\lim_{z\to 0}z^2 f(z)=1,\quad \lim_{z\to\omega}f(z)(z-\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{i\pi/6},\quad \lim_{z\to\omega}f(z)(z-\omega^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-i\pi/6}$$
we have:
$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{z}{z^2+z+1}+\frac{B}{z}+g(z) $$
where $B=-1$ since the sum of the residues must be zero.

Rearranging and checking that $g(z)=0$, we get:
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{e^{i\pi/6}}{\sqrt{3}(z-\omega)}+\frac{e^{-i\pi/6}}{\sqrt{3}(z-\omega^2)}=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{z}{z^2+z+1}.$$
Multypling by $z$ and rearranging we have:
$$ \frac{1}{z(z^2+z+1)}=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{-3+i\sqrt{3}}{6(z-\omega)}+\frac{-3-i\sqrt{3}}{6(z-\omega^2)}=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{z+1}{z^2+z+1}.$$

**(b)** Since 
$$\frac{z}{z^2+z+1}=\frac{e^{i\pi/6}}{\sqrt{3}(z-\omega)}+\frac{e^{-i\pi/6}}{\sqrt{3}(z+\omega)}$$
and
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z-\xi}\right)=e^{s\xi},$$
by linearity it follows that
$$\color{red}{\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{z^2+z+1}\right)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(e^{i\pi/6}e^{\omega s}+e^{-i\pi/6}e^{\omega^2 s}\right)=\color{red}{e^{-s/2}\left(\cos\frac{\sqrt{3}\,s}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sin\frac{\sqrt{3}\,s}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you soo much @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: Its a lot of typing work...Votes up people...